# regex search for integer in aggregate query mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have following collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b1fd21cc1448a422a21b3cc"),
    "amount" : 500,
    "bank" : "ICICI",
    "status" : "draft",
    "currency" : "EURO",
    "senderId" : ObjectId("5a16ca832bedaa6c4cb4ad97"),
    "created_date" : ISODate("2018-06-12T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```

I am searching for multiple criteria in it such like

```
const array = [
    { "status": { "$regex": searchString }},
    { "amount":  { "$regex": parseInt(searchString) }},
    { "created_date": searchString },
    { "currency": { "$regex": searchString }},
  ]

Invoice.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "$and":[{ "$or": array }] }}
])
```

But In above case `$regex` on amount searching in not working... It throws me an error...

How can I do this? I need to do this in aggregate query because I have to run `$lookup` for `senderId`

Comment: Numbers are not strings. You cannot do  a `$regex` on anything which is not a string.

Comment: @NeilLunn ok It cannot be possible for integer... So Is there any other way to do so?

Comment: Not in an aggregation `$match` no. You look like you're approaching this wrong anyway as you simply do not want to search "every" field in the document. if you're entering "text" as a search then just search the fields which have "text". If you want to let someone search by "amount", then make that a separate field in your search function and/or form. It's just makes no sense to look for "Hello" in a field which has only numeric values. And vice versa. Take the design tip and do it better.

Comment: ok thank you @NeilLunn... can I change my amount from integer to string using `$toString` or any other aggregation operator?

Comment: Don't even go there. Please listen to the plain common sense you've just been given. Forcing calculations is not what you need here. There just simply is not any valid reason to look for a string where something contains numbers. In the context of the linked duplicate, some people have "semi-valid" reasons such as searching telephone numbers. All you want is to "search every field in the document", and frankly that's just not a very smart implementation. And you can't use operators from unreleased versions anyway. Even if you did, it would need a "view" and be really slow.

Comment: Thank you @NeilLunn... You are piece of perfection I will follow your comments. thank you once again